# how to use multiple datasources in java application

Tags: jsf, oracle10g, ejb, glassfish-4

I have 2 schemes in the database, and I want to create an application that uses data from the other schema.
My question , can I use many database schemes' connection in one application?
I know that each 'ear' file must have one connection.
so how could I create an application with 2 connections?!

Comment: http://sscce.org/ please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **composite persistence unit** for this purpose. But this is slightly tough to handle, specially when anyone is a beginner. Please check these links for help:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/doc.1111/e25034/usingmultipledbs.htm

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Composite